# Equivalent of AnimationRunning->False in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, animation

I had an `Animate` environment with a continuous variable, but switched to `Manipulate` because I also wanted some user interaction while keeping the animation. In `Animate` I could specify `AnimationRunning->False`, but I can't figure out how to do that with `Manipulate`. The `AnimationRunning` option isn't allowed, and other things like `AutoAction->False` don't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == 4, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   Frame -> False, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], Graphics[{
    EdgeForm[Thin], Gray, Opacity[.2], Disk[{Sin[t], Cos[t]}, rad],
    Black, Opacity[1], Disk[{Sin[t], Cos[t]}, 0.01]}]],
 {t, RandomReal[500], Infinity}, {rad, .01, 1}]
```

In this case, since I have a nice periodic function, I know I don't have to use the `Infinity` endpoint, but my actual problem involves many functions of many different periods and I would like to keep the `t` parameter going without repeats. Here's a snapshot:

[image]

When I press `Shift`+`Enter` the point starts moving immediately, and I would like it to not move until I click the play button. So:

> How can I keep a continuous animation in `Manipulate` from executing when the whole cell is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set this option for the `Animator` controller used for `t`:

```
... {t, RandomReal[500], Infinity, AnimationRunning -> False} ...
```